# how to fix ERROR: Could not determine artifacts for com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3: Skipped due to earlier error

Tags: android, gradle

Just building my new app and after launching I get this error in my build.gradle file can anyone help?

```
    Could not determine artifacts for `com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3: Skipped due to earlier error`
```

I have made sure the app in settings is offline.

I also added jitpack.io into buildScript and "allprojects"

```
url "https://jitpack.io"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this build.gradle, it works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
}
```

and add this part to app gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean i should use the version 4.2.3 for appintro ?

Comment: Is everything OK? @FirasChebbah

Comment: Do you got the same error with my build.gradle suggestion?

Comment: I checked it again and it works well and no error appeared! @FirasChebbah